# How to set the video resolution over composite?

Tags: display, screen, config.txt, composite-video

I am trying to make a RPi 1 work nicely with an old LCD PAL TV ([Sony KLV-20SR3](http://pdf.crse.com/manuals/2067275121.pdf)). The video signal goes over composite (over SCART) because HDMI is not available. I am using LibreELEC.

By default the picture overflows the screen, but playing with `overscan_scale=1` and `overscan_{left,right,top,bottom}` I can make the display area right. The results are, however, ugly.

I suppose the problem is due to the fact that the RPi thinks that the resolution of the screen is 720x576 (probably due to `sdtv_mode=2 #PAL`) while the resolution of the LCD of this TV is exactly 640x480. I suppose that scaling the framebuffer is what makes everything blurry.

I tried setting `framebuffer_width=640` and `framebuffer_height=480` but the screen resolution is still the same. (If I read http://elinux.org/RPiconfig correctly, these settings work only for the console.)

How can I set the video resolution when using the composite output?

Answer (score 4):

I read at https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/composite-sd-resolution-of-osmc-skin-video-output/5445/3) that

> Composite is fixed resolution (720x480@60i for NTSC, 720x576@50i for PAL).

So you cannot change it.